# Authentication Problem - Order of execution of Observables and Promises (Angular / REST)

Tags: php, angular, typescript, authentication, jwt

I use Angular 7.

I'm new to angular and at the agency I work, we are going to create a new angular application.

A colleague of mine created the backend (Restful) and I started with the Authentication Feature.
So first of all we have an Layout with Topbar and Sidebar, they are on every screen.

After I have done the layout, I started with the Login Component, I also created an JWT Interceptor, to append the token to any header.
And created an AuthGuard to keep most of the paths protected.

I added an AuthenticationService with the functions login, logout and isAuthenticated.

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  public currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  public currentUser: Observable<User>;
  returnUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService,  private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("currentUser")) {
      const userId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).id;
      userService.getById(userId).subscribe((data) => {
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(data as User);
        this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
      });
    }
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    const authState = new Subject<boolean>();

    this.currentUser.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data) {
        authState.next(true);
      } else {
        authState.next(false);
      }
    });

    return authState.asObservable();
  }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`http://pitchbook.localhost/authentication_token`, {
      username: email,
      password
    })
        .pipe(map(object => {
          // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
          if (object.user && object.token) {
            this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';

            const jsonObject = {
              id: object.user.id,
              token: object.token
            };

            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(jsonObject));

            return jsonObject;
          }

          return object;
        }));
  }

  logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
    location.reload(true);
  }
}
```

And then I called login() in form Submit of the LoginComponent.

```
  onSubmit() {
    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.loginF.email.value, this.loginF.password.value)
        .pipe(first()).subscribe(
        (object) => {
          this.userService.getById(object.id as number).subscribe((data) => {
            this.authenticationService.currentUserSubject.next(data as User);
            this.authenticationService.currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserSubject.asObservable();

            console.log(this.authenticationService.currentUser);

            this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
            this.alertService.success("Success");
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.loading = false;
          this.alertService.error("Error");
        }
    );
  }
```

So the problem now is, that when I log in the get of the User with ID takes too long and the navigate to "/dashboard" happens before.
After that the AuthGuard is trying to get the currentUser of the AuthenticationService, but it is still not there and so i get kicked back to "/login" and have to login again.
After i'm kicked to "/login" the currentUser is set in the AuthGuard Service, but it's too late now and i can't subscribe it, because it is undefined at first call.

I tried to get the User inside of the pipe in the login function of the AuthenticationService, but it did not work.

The result i expect is, that i press the login button, the currentUser is set (get User from API with ID (because the user object is pretty big and should not be completely in response of authentication request))

I get navigated to /dashboard and in the topbar I can see my username.

But in the hidden, the AuthGuard should watch if the user is Authenticated, if not navigate to /login.

After Page refresh, I want to stay loggedin

I hope you guys can understand what i mean, if not feel free to ask.
I can append some lines of code or can show other components, if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with the way you're using RxJS. You should not overwrite Observables variables this way.

In `AuthenticationService` declare `currentUser` this way:

```
  public readonly currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
```

And remove the folowing from the `onSubmit()` method.

```
this.authenticationService.currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
```

The `isAuthenticated` method is badly written (leaking subscription), a better way may be:

```
  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.currentUser.pipe(map(user => !!user));
  }
```

Comment: What is the best way to set the currentUser Variable inside the AuthenticationService? If I define the Variable that way, the currentUserSubject might not be defined.

Comment: ```this.authenticationService.currentUserSubject.next(user);``` Do not update the `curentUser` variable directly.

Comment: The `currentUserSubject` must be defined in AuthenticationService contructor : ```readonly currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null)```.

Comment: Okay that seem to work. I get redirect to /dashboard, but after an reload i have to login again.

Comment: This is another story. You will have to get the token from the localStore, request the `User` **before** your Angular application is initialized. **APP_INITIALIZER** is the keyword to solve this.

Comment: Hm yeah, but it's pretty hard to implement.
I'm using my AuthService and my UserService.
How do I know, which dependencies are the needed one, to get this app running?
```Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency!```

Comment: Okay got it now.
Had to use Injector for Router and ActivatedRoute.

Now, my last question is, how can I run JS Code after *ngIf in Template.
I have my TopBar Component and it gets initalized without a logged in user, so the Username etc is not shown.

So I want if the user is logged in and the Username is shown in the topbar, to run some JavaScript code, which initalizes an Popup on the Component

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're talking about. Something like : ```<div class="top-bar">{{ (authentication.currentUser | async)?.username }}</div>```

Comment: I have to run JavaScript Code, after the Component gets created.
But that depends on the *ngIf.
My JS code is initialized before the component is created.